# Entity Framework with Moq: DbSet.Add not working in Unit Test

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, moq, xunit

I'm new to EF and I've run into a hurdle. I'm currently testing a method using Moq and Xunit that adds an object to the database. The method works when I try it with the regular database, but with the mocked database it's not really working.

This is my method that I'm testing:

```
public async Task<int> insertarRolAsync(Rol rol, DbContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try 
    {
        context.Roles.Add(rol);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        return context.Roles.Last().RolId;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        output.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return 99;
    }
}
```

During normal execution, it works properly. However, using a mock database, the new rol object isn't added.

This is my test, which compares the value of the RolId returned by the handler:

```
[Fact]
public async Task<Task> InsertarRolAsyncTest()
{
    var insert = new Rol
            {
                Nombre = "RolInsert",
                tipo_de_usuario= 1
            };
                      
    var valores = await _handler.insertarRolAsync(insert,_handler._context,CancellationToken.None);
    output.WriteLine("Valores:" + valores);

    Assert.IsType<int>(valores);
    Assert.NotEqual(99, valores);
    Assert.True(valores > 3);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

And this is my current mock data configuration:

```
public static void SetupDbContextData(this Mock<DbContext> mockContext)
{
    var roles = new List<Rol>
           {
               new Rol
                   {
                       RolId = 1,
                       Nombre = "Consumidor",
                       tipo_de_usuario = 3
                   },
               new Rol
                   {
                       RolId = 2,
                       Nombre = "Proveedor",
                       tipo_de_usuario = 2
                   },
               new Rol
                   {
                       RolId = 3,
                       Nombre = "Administrador",
                       tipo_de_usuario = 3
                   }
           };
    }

    ...
    //some other mocked data for other tests
    ...
    mockContext.Setup(x => x.Roles).Returns(roles.AsQueryable().BuildMockDbSet().Object);
    mockContext.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<Rol>())).Callback<Rol>((s) => roles.Add(s));
}
```

And for context, the test class constructor includes this:

```
_contextMock = new Mock<DbContext>();
_contextMock.SetupDbContextData();
_handler = new InsertarRolCommandHandler(_contextMock.Object,output);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not really obtaining any error codes or exceptions until I hit the failed Assert, so I'm not sure how to proceed here. Thank you!

Comment: Don't unit test entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

`context.Roles.Add(rol);` is invoking the add method on the dbset, where as your mock setup  `mockContext.Setup(d => d.Add(` is setting up the add method on the context, which is a different thing.

I'm not sure what library exposes `.BuildMockDbSet()`, but support for what you're trying to do will depend on whether it sets up the mutation methods.

The usual options are:

- Use a real DB
- Use an in-memory provider (though I see you're using async efcore methods, so YMMV)
- Use another mocking library that supports the functionality (mocking the dbcontext is a highly opinionated debate, I'm not going there); I maintain a library - https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing - that will probably do it - there may be others as well